# Using only PHP, how to Import to wordpress post data and saving into post_content a WPbakery template

Tags: php, json, wordpress, templates, wpbakery

Using PHP exclusively.. From external json data I'd like to import to wp_posts table and directly apply a WPbakery template to these new posts

From a

```
"SELECT option_value FROM wp_options where option_name='wpb_js_templates'"
```

I got all template data, my issue is how to retrieve the portion of data to apply to the new field wp_posts.post_content

And also the css needs to be writen to

```
wp_postmeta (using meta_key => '_wpb_shortcodes_custom_css'
```

Does anyone has done this before? Please, could you share with us how?

TIA

Comment: Why are you reading _option values_, what does that have to do with creating the posts or their meta data? Why don’t you know where to take the actual post content from - isn’t that what you get from your external JSON to begin with? Overall very unclear what you actually want here, this needs a way better description than what you have given us so far. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question to include a sufficient level of detail.

Comment: there is two source of data... from the json data I get title, date and others info to be stored as postmeta.. to be stored to the post_content field I need to apply a WPbakery's template

Comment: That phrasing makes rather little sense, you don’t “apply a template”, not to individual post data. You probably want to execute some filters the template might have defined for post content or something like that.

Comment: Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do (this is a mysql browser):

http://sociofortaleza.tk/external_assets/Capture.JPG

Comment: That would be what you want to get then? That does not explain where you want to get this data _from_. Start by explaining what you get from your external JSON. And whether you want to create new posts, or update something for already existing ones.

Comment: It isn't a fixed data.. it is variable... and it is saved by the user here:

sociofortaleza.tk/external_assets/Capture2.JPG

Comment: from a json I get the data from an external source.. it is sports information...

Comment: from stored wpbakery, I take the format as this json data will be shown on frontend

Comment: here is a sample what I need to write to the field post_content (this data was got from wp_options table from wpbakery plugin):

[vc_row full_width="stretch_row" msp_template="match-page-football-simple" css=".vc_custom_1491051052586{padding-bottom: 39px !important;background-color: #ffffff !important;}"][vc_column css=".vc_custom_1491051069876{border-bottom-width: 1px !important;border-bottom-color: #cccccc !important;}"][team_match_header page_context="true" css_animation="flipInX"]

*start of the data only (the comments are char size limited)

Comment: My issue is because I am stucked now, on how to parse this data using php.. separating the wpbakery's template portion  and the css portion to give them different destinies